# Application Insights Logging Twice

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics

I have a .NET 8 v4 dotnet-isolated Azure Function app.

Upon examining some logs, I discovered one set of traces that were logged (via `logger.LogInformation(...)`) twice. (i.e. each trace item was duplicated--EXCEPT for the *itemId*, which was unique for each item) These were logged during the processing of a timer-triggered function.

This is the only time I have seen this happen.

During the same processing, I also recorded some custom events (via `telemetry.TrackEvent(...)`). These were not duplicated, as the traces were.

Can someone explain this? Under what conditions can this occur?

Comment: Is it ongoing regularly or was it scoped to a period of time? One scenario where it is possible is when ingestion endpoint having issues and SDK retries. Then if ingestion endpoint actually successfully ingested data but SDK didn't get 200 (timeout, got 500) - it can result in duplicates.

Comment: @ZakiMa It was just for a particular period of time. Interesting scenario... if that is possible, the API should be designed to have a (hidden) GUID in each log write--and then duplicates could be filtered out by the ingestion endpoint

Comment: @DonnyKwitty, Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: @Pavan Sure... logger.LogInformation("You logged me twice! Doh!");

Comment: Can you update the question with code which you have tried?

Comment: Your main requirement is control the duplicate logs which Every log getting twice right?